# A small mammal?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, poetry

> Small mammal – I'm
>   A
>   International animal
>   With four legs, and,
>   Whiskers. Sharp eyes.
>   But, it wouldn't do
>   
>   To totally give up
>   A
>   Answer, too readily,
>   So those are all the
>   Clues that I am going
>   To give you; sorry!

Comment: Are the formats intentional?

Comment: I don't get it. There's an answer that seems obvious to me but there's nothing enigmatic about it....  (So I,m guessing it's wrong) - a bit more info on the format could help. Like Alex said (the obvious answer is that yes the format is intentional, but is example the second A not 'an' so it fits the format or regardless of format would still be A? Because the correct sentence would be 'But it wouldn't do to totally give up **an** answer too readily.' )  etc..

Comment: @Spacemonkey, the first A should be an An as well.

Comment: Hi all - I [don't want to give any clues](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuE_jqYNi3c) as that would spoil the fun, but suffice it to say that I'm happy the poem doesn't need any further editing. The way it's shown above is correct.

Comment: It looks like fill in the blanks: what goes after the a.

Comment: and maybe between the two paragraphs as well. It looks like the last sentence of the first paragraph and the first one on the last paragraph are one sentence that's missing some words.

Comment: Are we supposed to read this in the voice of William Shatner? Because I just can't help myself.

Comment: @Kingrames Absolutely. In the voice of Shatner doing "Lucy. In the Sky. With Diamonds!"

Comment: What are the chances you'll tell us how many letters the answer we're looking for is...?

Comment: Any hint of any kind would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Impressive construction!

> Count the number of characters, including punctuation and spaces, in each line.
>
>  18 1 20 20 21 19
>  18 1 20 20 21 19
>
>  Use the simple alphanumeric cipher 1=A, 2=B, 3=C, etc.
>
>  RATTUS
>  RATTUS
>
>  You're *Rattus rattus* or the **[black rat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_rat)**!

Answer (score 3):

I decided to post it anyway:

> A Lynx
>  It's a small mammal (4-legged with whisker) found in northern europe, siberia, asia and north america. Felines are generally known to be the mammals with the best eyesight. The Canadian Lynx is the smallest of all lynx species. They are generally very hard to spot in the wild. But this has nothing to do with an enigmatic-puzzle, so it must be wrong! Sorry*

Comment: Nice try, but no, I'm afraid that's not the answer I was thinking of. Thanks for getting the ball rolling though! :)

Comment: It also LINKS the first stanza to the second stanza...eh? Eh?

Comment: @BaileyM I thought about that right away (I'm A Lynx (links)) but can't find anything to fit the second one